Running a python child process concurrently doesn't seem to be concurrent
I've been tasked to update an existing python program that currently runs as a single process, to run a child process concurrently. I'm new to python concurrency techniques and wrote a simple script to see how to do this using the multiprocessing library:
import datetime
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def child_operation():
    """Run a child process."""
    name = 'child'
    period = 1
    logging.info(f"{datetime.datetime.now()}: started operation {name}")
    for i in range(10):
        logging.info(f"operation {name}, {i=}: sleeping for period {period} sec")
        time.sleep(period)
    logging.info(f"{datetime.datetime.now()}: ended operation {name}")


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')

    main_sleep_period: int = 5

    # Spawn a process
    process = Process(target=child_operation())
    process.start()

    # Now do something in main while process is running
    logging.info(f'main: sleeping for {main_sleep_period} sec')  # XX
    time.sleep(main_sleep_period)
    logging.info('main stopped sleeping')

    process.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

So the child process runs for about 10 seconds. I expected the line marked 'XX' in the 'main' process to run shortly after the child process starts. However I always find that this line appears after the child process completes its operation:
2024-08-23 13:32:56,946 2024-08-23 13:32:56.946205: started operation child
2024-08-23 13:32:56,946 operation child, i=0: sleeping for period 1 sec
2024-08-23 13:32:57,946 operation child, i=1: sleeping for period 1 sec
2024-08-23 13:32:58,947 operation child, i=2: sleeping for period 1 sec
2024-08-23 13:32:59,948 operation child, i=3: sleeping for period 1 sec
2024-08-23 13:33:00,949 operation child, i=4: sleeping for period 1 sec
2024-08-23 13:33:01,950 operation child, i=5: sleeping for period 1 sec
2024-08-23 13:33:02,951 operation child, i=6: sleeping for period 1 sec
2024-08-23 13:33:03,952 operation child, i=7: sleeping for period 1 sec
2024-08-23 13:33:04,953 operation child, i=8: sleeping for period 1 sec
2024-08-23 13:33:05,953 operation child, i=9: sleeping for period 1 sec
2024-08-23 13:33:06,954 2024-08-23 13:33:06.954231: ended operation child
2024-08-23 13:33:06,976 main: sleeping for 5 sec
2024-08-23 13:33:11,978 main stopped sleeping

I guess I'm doing something silly. I tried to google for examples but the ones I've seen only show how multiple child processes run concurrently, but not one where we have a main process and a child process and how they interplay.
Can someone point me to my error?

Perhaps you need to pass child_operation as a callable, without the (). I mean:

instead of this: process = Process(target=child_operation())
try this: process = Process(target=child_operation)

Let's see how that goes

Yes, I just discovered that error and was going to withdraw my question. Too late! In any case that was the fix, thanks!

Similar problem (with threading this time) but with similar solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78809518/python-3-9-13-multithreading-issue
